Why do I need to say "new" so many times in pkl (in particular to get json arrays)?
This pkl code:
class Check_run_delete_olds {
  hidden days: Int
  hidden shortname: String
  name = "\(shortname) Runs OK And At Least Once In The Past \(days) Day(s)"
  filters: Any
}

imapserver = "imap.gmail.com"
login = "me@gmail.com"
password = "nope"
handlers = new Dynamic {
  new Check_run_delete_olds {
    shortname = "foo"
    days = 3
    filters = new Dynamic {
      new { Match = new { From = " <puppet_cron_stodi@myhost.org>$" } }
      new { Match = new { Subject = "^Cron " } }
      new { Match = new { Subject = "puppet agent" } }
    }
  }
}

does exactly what I want, which is to produce the following output:
$ ./pkl eval -f json test.pkl
{
  "imapserver": "imap.gmail.com",
  "login": "me@gmail.com",
  "password": "nope",
  "handlers": [
    {
      "name": "foo Runs OK And At Least Once In The Past 3 Day(s)",
      "filters": [
        {
          "Match": {
            "From": " <puppet_cron_stodi@myhost.org>$"
          }
        },
        {
          "Match": {
            "Subject": "^Cron "
          }
        },
        {
          "Match": {
            "Subject": "puppet agent"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

But wow does it sure seem like I'm saying "new" a lot.  In particular, it seems like I have to say "new" all over the place to get a json array of objects.
Is there some cleaner / more idiomatic way to get the same output?

Here's a version with less news.
class Check_run_delete_olds {
  hidden days: Int
  hidden shortname: String
  name = "\(shortname) Runs OK And At Least Once In The Past \(days) Day(s)"
  filters: Any
}

imapserver = "imap.gmail.com"
login = "me@gmail.com"
password = "nope"
handlers {
  (Check_run_delete_olds) {
    shortname = "foo"
    days = 3
    filters = (Dynamic) {
      new { Match { From = " <puppet_cron_stodi@myhost.org>$" } }
      new { Match { Subject = "^Cron " } }
      new { Match { Subject = "puppet agent" } }
    }
  }
}


Weird you can drop the equals like that, but that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!
